# Difference between aws s3 cli grants and Java API AccessControlList when uploading object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

Using the aws s3 cli, I can upload a file using the "cp" command and, at the same time, grant a specific user full control by ID using the "--grants" option and it works.

However, when using the Java API, I am using the AccessControlList and using grantPermission to give a specific user full control by ID and then associating the AccessControlList with the PutObjectRequest, but I am not achieving the same result.

Is there a distinction between how the "--grants" option works on the cli "cp" command and the AccessControlList in the PutObjectRequest in the API?

Note that the upload is conditional on that user getting full control (the upload gets "access denied" otherwise).

Thanks.

Comment: [Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#withAccessControlList-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AccessControlList-) says "PutObjectRequest ... applies a canned access control policy to the new object".  Then later, withAccessControlList "Sets the optional access control list for the new object. If specified, cannedAcl will be ignored." Sounds like the obj needs to be created first (?).  Have you tried withCannedAcl ?

Comment: The object cannot be created unless that user ID has full control, otherwise the access is denied (see my last note).

Comment: Yeah.  What about using [SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-iam.html) Managing IAM Users?